# Set JRadioButton to true based on a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, jlabel

I have two JFrames, the first one is used to display SQL table using JTable and the second one is used to update the data on the SQL table. On the first frame, there's a button used to show the second frame and it has radio buttons. However, I can't set it to `true`. What I want to happen is set the radio button to true based on what value I get from a Label where the Label's value came from the database. Here's what I have done:

**FIRST JFRAME:**

```
private void btnUpdateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
 String hours = null;
  try
    {
        DbUpdate up = new DbUpdate();

        // To connect on SQL and get the JTable's value
        int get = (int)jTable2.getModel().getValueAt(jTable2.getSelectedRow(), 0);
        String query= "SELECT * FROM roominfo WHERE CustomerNo = '"+get+"' " ;

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/adve"; 
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","sa"); 
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);

        while(rs.next())
        {
        hours= rs.getString("Hours"); // This is where I can get the value for hours and to be passed on a label
        }
         up.jLabel12.setText(hours); //I set on a Jlabel for the next frame
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select a record to update");
    }

}
```

**SECOND JFRAME:**

```
  public void set(){ //THIS SUPPOSE TO SET THE BUTTONS BASED ON THE VALUE OF THE LABEL
if (jLabel12.getText().equals("12-Hours")) { // if 12-Hours, Rdn12 should be true or selected
   Rdn12.isSelected();
   Rdn12.setSelected(true);
   Rdn24.setSelected(false);
 }
 else if (jLabel12.getText().equals("24-Hours")) { // if 24-Hours, Rdn24 should be true or selected
   Rdn12.setSelected(false);
   Rdn24.setSelected(true);
 }    
  jTextField1.setEditable(false);
  jLabel20.setVisible(false);

}
```

However, The radiobutton still won't get selected. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions? Please help.

Comment: What happens? What errors occur?

Comment: No errors but I can't set the radio button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
private void btnUpdateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
String hours = null;
 try
    {
        DbUpdate up = new DbUpdate();

        int get = (int)jTable2.getModel().getValueAt(jTable2.getSelectedRow(), 0);
        String query= "SELECT * FROM roominfo WHERE CustomerNo = '"+get+"' " ;

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/adv"; 
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","sa"); 
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);


        while(rs.next())
        {
         hours= rs.getString("Hours");
}
 if (hours.equals("12-Hours")) {
        // you can change the fields of the second frame directly in here
        up.Rdn12.isSelected();
        up.Rdn12.setSelected(true);
        up.Rdn24.setSelected(false);

    } else if (hours.equals("24-Hours")) {
        up.Rdn24.isSelected();
        up.Rdn12.setSelected(false);
        up.Rdn24.setSelected(true);
    }

    }
    catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select a record to update");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** I don't know, whether I did quite understand your question. Is this application kind of what you were looking for?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class DatabaseRadioButtons extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DatabaseRadioButtons().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    JTable table = new JTable();
    JButton showSecondFrame = new JButton("Show second frame");
    SecondFrame secondFrame = new SecondFrame();

    public DatabaseRadioButtons() {

        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {
                new Object[] { "first", "entry" },
                new Object[] { "second", "entry" } }, new Object[] { "column",
                "names" }));
        ListSelectionModel selectionModel = table.getSelectionModel();
        selectionModel.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if (e.getValueIsAdjusting())
                    return; // ignore this event, if we expect another event
                            // right after this one

                int selectedRow = table.getSelectedRow();
                refreshRadioButtonsAccordingToDatabaseValues(selectedRow);
            }
        });

        showSecondFrame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        secondFrame.setVisible(true);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(showSecondFrame, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setContentPane(panel);
        setSize(400, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    protected void refreshRadioButtonsAccordingToDatabaseValues(int selectedRow) {

        String databaseValue;

        // put you database SELECT here, instead of this fixed value
        System.out.println("Make Database select for row " + selectedRow);
        databaseValue = selectedRow == 0 ? "12-Hours" : "24-Hours";

        // Choose what to do, according to database values
        if (databaseValue.equals("12-Hours")) {

            // you can change the fields of the second frame directly in here
            secondFrame.Rdn12.isSelected();
            secondFrame.Rdn12.setSelected(true);
            secondFrame.Rdn24.setSelected(false);
        } else if (databaseValue.equals("24-Hours")) {
            secondFrame.Rdn12.setSelected(false);
            secondFrame.Rdn24.setSelected(true);
        }
    }

}

class SecondFrame extends JFrame {

    JRadioButton Rdn12 = new JRadioButton("Radio 12");
    JRadioButton Rdn24 = new JRadioButton("Radio 24");

    public SecondFrame() {
        setSize(400, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocation(100, 100);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10, 1));
        panel.add(Rdn12);
        panel.add(Rdn24);
        setContentPane(panel);
    }
}
```

You can change a value of a Label in your Second Frame, but you don't necessarily have to. As my example shows you can just change your checkboxes of your second frame from within the code of your first frame.

Update the `refreshRadioButtonsAccordingToDatabaseValues()` method to read actual data from your database.

Comment: Err.. I don't use the jLabel20. It's just an extra label.
I only used jLabel12 to set the buttons as 12-Hours or 24-Hours.

Comment: You set `hours` to 12-Hours. What I need to do is to get it from the database and set it on a JLabel then when the second frame opens up,  radiobutton will set to true based on the JLabel's text.

Comment: I had to comment the database specific code, so that I was able to run the code without database. Just remove the "//"s in my code. If you want the code to be executed whenever a "SecondFrame"-instance is created, that you could try to move the database-code into the consturctor of "SecondFrame".

Comment: How can I do that?
I need to click a row on a JTable first before I can get all the value from the database to my second frame.

Comment: I tried setting the JLabel's text to "12-Hours" and it successfully gets the radiobutton to be selected. I also tried putting the database code away first and it's also successful. I don't know why it is like that. What I need is to set it to JLabel from the database which doesn't work.